# white-box cryptography and its applications

Tags: white-box

I am a programmer who is doing research into *whitebox cryptography*.

What I hope to do is to use WBC for an DRM application however as some of us may know, WBC is theoretically impossible therefore I am currently trying to find out how other people have been using WBC and learn from their examples.

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you already found it, but a good starting point for research on this subject would be [whiteboxcrypto.com](http://whiteboxcrypto.com)

It took me a while to understand exactly how white-box is used some sort of securely - not so much because the key can be recovered from the white box - but because one can isolate the white-box and use it's encrypt or decrypt functionality to do whatever they want, without even needing the key
(See also [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/why-to-try-get-key-out-of-white-box-crypto-how-can-one-protect-wbc-itself)).

The way DRM is implemented in practice is as a mix of standard obfuscation techniques (tricks to make code unreadable) and white-box crypto (a cryptographic algorithm implemented as a network of encoded lookup tables$^*$).
Standard obfuscation techniques are a quite effective way of protecting DRM, but they have a big flaw: they cannot really protect the key in cryptographic algorithms. White-box crypto can do exactly that, but is not very effective in protecting access to itself. Combined however they are pretty good.

Of course, neither general obfuscation techniques nor white-box techniques currently are impossible to crack - they just make it a lot harder (more expensive) to do.

$^*$ Assuming you are using symmetric algorithms like AES or DES